# Re-using a single file with basic ruby tested code in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-reuse

I got this code in a single file snippet.rb and it runs as expected. This script if from dzone snippet that fetches the thumbnail of the URL at the current time.

Now I wan to integrate this functionality with Rails and here I'm stuck how to begin.
Should I put this in some ruby file inside lib directory or make it modules???
I'm not much fluent in Ruby, so can anyone plz initiate me how and where to start??

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'xmlsimple'

    class Nailer

        @@api_baseurl = 'http://webthumb.bluga.net/api.php'
        @@api_key = 'YOUR-API-KEY'

        attr_accessor :collection_time, :job_id, :ok

        def initialize(url, width = 1024, height = 768)
            url = url.gsub!(/&/, '&amp;')
            api_request = 
    %Q{<webthumb><apikey>#{@@api_key}</apikey><request><url>#{url}</url><width>#{width}</width><height>#{height}</height></request></webthumb>}

            result = do_request(api_request)

            if result.class == Net::HTTPOK
              result_data = XmlSimple.xml_in(result.body)
              @job_id = result_data['jobs'].first['job'].first['content']
              @collection_time = Time.now.to_i + result_data['jobs'].first['job'].first['estimate'].to_i
              @ok = true
            else
              @ok = false
            end
        end

        def retrieve(size = :small)
            api_request = 
    %Q{<webthumb><apikey>#{@@api_key}</apikey><fetch><job>#{@job_id}</job><size>#{size.to_s}</size></fetch></webthumb>}
            result = do_request(api_request)
            result.body
        end

        def retrieve_to_file(filename, size = :small)
            File.new(filename, 'w+').write(retrieve(size.to_s))
        end

        def ready?
            return unless Time.now.to_i >= @collection_time

            api_request = %Q{<webthumb><apikey>#{@@api_key}</apikey><status><job>#{@job_id}</job></status></webthumb>}
            result = do_request(api_request)

            if result.class == Net::HTTPOK
              @ok = true
              result_data = XmlSimple.xml_in(result.body)
              begin
                @result_url = result_data['jobStatus'].first['status'].first['pickup']
                @completion_time = result_data['jobStatus'].first['status'].first['completionTime']
              rescue
                @collection_time += 60 
                  return false
              end
            else
              @ok = false
            end

            true
        end

        def ok?
            @ok == true
        end

        def wait_until_ready
            sleep 1 until ready?
        end

        private

        def do_request(body)
            api_url = URI.parse(@@api_baseurl)
            request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(api_url.path)
            request.body = body
            Net::HTTP.new(api_url.host, api_url.port).start {|h| h.request(request) }
        end
    end

    url = 'http://www.rubyinside.com/'
    t = Nailer.new(url)

    if t.ok?
        t.wait_until_ready
        t.retrieve_to_file('out1.jpg', :small)
        t.retrieve_to_file('out2.jpg', :medium)
        t.retrieve_to_file('out3.jpg', :medium2)
        t.retrieve_to_file('out4.jpg', :large)
        puts "Thumbnails saved"
    else
        puts "Error"
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

Put it in `lib/nailer.rb`, and you're good to go. Rails' autoloading lets you use `Nailer.new(...)` and such without any configurations or requires.

Answer (score 0):

The lib directory is a good place for utility code like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you can just drop this straight in to your lib/ directory in a file called nailer.rb, and you should be good to go.  Since lib/ is in your load path in a Rails app, a simple `"require 'nailer'"` at the top of any given file should be all you need to pull the class in to your name space.

You *could* also put it in app/models - it's totally ok to put non-ActiveRecord models in there.  Since this isn't exactly a data model in your domain, though, I think lib/ is probably the better place.